# Does 'string.format' allow more control over iterables / dictionaries?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am in a situation where it is easy to adjust the formatting string, but hard to adjust the arguments for format:

```
'I can influence this'.format(foo={'a': 'no', 'b': 'control'},
                              bar=['no', 'control', 'either'])
```

For numbers, you can format with `{:1.23f}`.

For dates, you can format with [`{:%Y-%m-%d}`](http://strftime.org/).

I would like to have more control for iterables and for dictionaries. For example, I could imagine `'{:iterable.42}'` to access the 43st element of an iterable and `{:dict.b}` to access the element with the key `b`.

Does something like that exist?

Comment: You mean like `'{mylist[2]}'.format(mylist=['no', 'no', 'yes'])`? You might need to give a more explanatory example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access to keyword arguments specified in the function format while formatting your string:

```py
'{foo[a]} {bar[1]}'.format(foo={'a': 'no', 'b': 'control'},
                              bar=['no', 'control', 'either'])
```

A useful source for formatting string in python:
https://pyformat.info/